# What are the implications of using a variable declared outside of an async context as a placeholder for its return values?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I understand that if the variable was declared outside of the function, it should be marked as `global`. But what about this case? Is it safe to do something like:

```py
async def foo():
    items = []
    async with SomeClient() as client:
        fetched_items = await client.get_items()

        for item in fetched_items:
            items.append(item)

    return items
```

Comment: Yes. `async` and `with` don't establish a new scope. Only functions and classes create scopes.

Comment: FWIW you can just `return list(await ...)`. The `items = []` is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is completely safe. `with` statements do not create a new scope.

As for your code, you can easily refactor it:

```
async def foo():
    async with SomeClient() as client:
        return list(await client.get_items())
```